# UWP client using HttpClient to communicate with .NET Web API, failed connection when SSL is enabled

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, win-universal-app

I'm doing a project where I need to communicate with a Web API from a UWP-application.

I use HttpClient to do the job, and it works fine as long as the Web API is not using SSL. When I turn the SSL on, it just won't work. It works if I use some other client though, like browser/Wpf-application/console-application.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to allow unsigned / self signed certificates. If so, you can do it the following way

```
var filter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
filter.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(ChainValidationResult.Untrusted);

var httpClient = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient(filter);
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, that is uselul. Unfortunately I'm using the System.Net.Http and not the web.http one. But I did not specify that, so that's on me!

I decided to simply turn off SSL for now (this application is not something to be shipped, so security is not a "real" issue at the moment).